# React-Native - make component draggable only when pressing on a child of the component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

**Scenario & requirement:**

I am building a `<SortableListView>` component and I want the `<ListItem>`s only be draggable when the user press on a specific child element of the list item, e.g. the 'drag handle'.

[image]

**My current solution:**

Set a flag to true when the drag handle is pressed and use the flag to determine whether to grant the `<ListItem>` the pan responder to make it draggable.

1. Drag handle `onPressIn` triggered.
2. Set var `handlePressed` to `true`.
3. `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder` of the `<ListItem>` returns `true` if `handlePressed` is `true`, thus enables the list item to be draggable.
4. Set var `handlePressed` back to `false` when `onPanResponderRelease` of the `<ListItem>` fires.

**The problem of my solution:**

There is a very noticeable delay between pressing the drag handle and getting the response of `onPressIn`. So if I press and quickly move away from the drag handle, the pan responder will be granted to the `<ListItem>` after my touch point have already left the drag handle.

As a result, the `<ListItem>` won't start to follow my gesture movement immediately after I press on the drag handle. Instead, there will be an offset between my touch point and the list item being dragged. If I press and wait until the pan responder is granted then everything works just fine.

[image]